# Value of the integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}x^2e^{xy}dxdy.$$

**My approach:** $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}x^2e^{xy}dxdy=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{x^2e^{xy}}{y}-2x\frac{e^{xy}}{y^2}+2\frac{e^{xy}}{y^3}-\frac{2}{y^3}\right)dy.$

After this, I do not know how to proceed. If I continue integrating, I am getting lost.

Comment: You should integrate wrt y first.

Comment: Your solution is a function of $x$, not a number!

Comment: You should change order of $dx$ and $dy$ in the first integral, right? The inner integral is probably wrt $y$.

Comment: @mickep: The question was exactly as I wrote it. The order of $dx$ and $dy$ confused me. However, as is explained in the comments below, I think the limits of the integration should give an idea about associating the correct variables with their integrals. As Ron Gordon mentions, $dxdy$ is an area element and equal to $dydx$. Correct me if I seem wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^x dy \, e^{x y} = \frac{e^{x^2}-1}{x} $$

$$\int_0^1 dx \, x^2 \, \int_0^x dy \, e^{x y} = \int_0^1 dx \, x \left (e^{x^2} - 1 \right)  = \frac12(e-1) - \frac12 = \frac12 (e-2)$$

Comment: The solution of the integral should be related to $x$...

Comment: @k1.M: I have no idea what you are talking about.  This is a definite integral, whose *evaluation* results in a number.  The integration is carried out with respect to $y$ first, then $x$.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{x} x^2e^{xy}dx$ is a function like $f(x,y)$, hence $\int_{0}^{1} f(x,y)dy$ is a function of $y$. Observe that the notation $\int_{0}^{x} f(x)dx$ is an ambiguous notation for $ \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$.

Comment: @k1.M: What sort of logical gymnastics are you putting yourself into to believe that?  You are willfully misinterpreting the problem and then resolving the resulting logical fallacy with a reference to "ambiguous notation."  There is nothing ambiguous about this problem.  The result is a number.  BTW I write the differentials first in my integrals to make the association of a variable of integration and its integral absolutely clear.  But even in standard notation as above, there is no room for ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x}x^2 e^{xy}\,dy\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}x^3 e^{x^2 z}\,dz\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}x\left(e^{x^2}-1\right)\,dx=\frac{e-2}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that if
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x}x^2e^{xy}dxdy=\int_{0}^{x} \int_{0}^{1}x^2e^{xy}dydx$$
Then by fundamental theorem of calculus
$$F'(x)=\int_{0}^{1} x^2e^{xy}dy=x^2\int_{0}^{1} e^{xy}dy=x(e^x-1)$$

Comment: How on earth is this relevant?  Or even coherent?  Please, explain your "reversal" of the order of integration.

Comment: You can integrate of $F'(x)$ to get $F(x)$ up to a constant, but also we have $F(0)=0$

Comment: Your misunderstanding of standard mathematical notation - and integration generally - is a disservice to the OP and other people who read these pages.  Please stop.

Comment: Observe that we have $dxdy$ instead of $dydx$. So at firs you should integrate the inner integral by respect to $x$ (here ambiguity arose)  and then find a function of $x$, and then integrate respect to $y$. As question owner did.

Comment: Observe that what you end up with is nonsense.  Yes, the $dx dy$ may be seen in isolation to be ambiguous.  But the integration limits take care of any ambiguity.  Ultimately, the meaning is resolved in the final result.  You do see that your strict interpretation of $dx dy$ results in ambiguity in which you seem to feel comfortable.  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I saw the notation $\int_{0}^{x} f(x)dx$ instead of $int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$ in some mathematical papers and books earlier, some mathematicians like Hardy use this notation for having lower number of variables, but makes ambiguity! And this problem is a good reason for us to don't use this notation... I used it because the owner did.

Comment: The OP got lost in his notation and ran into trouble.  Note, however, that $dx dy$ is really an area element and is thus equivalent to $dy dx$ in an informal sense.  The OP's informality should not be taken at face value.  It should be clear that he was asking for a number.  Your choice of strict interpretation one way and very loose interpretation in other ways is a potpourri of choices designed to obfuscate where the intention is quite clear.